# parametricplot issue

Tags: plotting

I need to plot `x2[x1[t]]` using `ParametricPlot`. However the output is an empty plot. My code:

```
eqn1 = x1'[t] + x2[t] == (-3/10)*x1[t];
eqn2 = x1[t] - x2'[t] == 1;
subjectto = {x1[0] == 1/2, x2[0] == 0};
sol1 = DSolve[Join[{eqn1, eqn2}, subjectto], {x1, x2}, t]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x2[x1[t]]} /. sol1], {t, -10, 10}]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: `x2` is a function of  time, not `x1`, so try `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol1], {t, -10, 10}]`

Comment: You need `Plot`not `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Or you need to give two coordinates to `ParametricPlot`, not one as in your example. E.g. `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t],x2[t]]} /. sol1], {t, -10, 10}]`  -- You have to pay attention to such details in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some bells and whistles to the solution given by `Chris K` and `Michael E2`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

eqn1 = x1'[t] + x2[t] == (-3/10)*x1[t];
eqn2 = x1[t] - x2'[t] == 1;
subjectto = {x1[0] == 1/2, x2[0] == 0};

sys = Join[{eqn1, eqn2}, subjectto];

sol1 = DSolve[sys, {x1, x2}, t][[1]];
```

Verifying the solution,

```
sys /. sol1 // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

The simplified forms

```
funcs = {x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol1 // FullSimplify

(* {1 - 1/782 E^(-3 t/
    20) (391 Cos[(Sqrt[391] t)/20] + 9 Sqrt[391] Sin[(Sqrt[391] t)/20]), -(3/
   10) + (
  E^(-3 t/
    20) (1173 Cos[(Sqrt[391] t)/20] - 91 Sqrt[391] Sin[(Sqrt[391] t)/20]))/
  3910} *)

lim = Limit[funcs, t -> Infinity]

(* {1, -(3/10)} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[Tooltip[funcs, sys], {t, -10, tmax},
  PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 3.2}, {-2.5, 1.4}},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x1[t], x2[t]}),
  ColorFunction ->
   Function[{x1, x2, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-10, tmax}},
    LegendLabel -> Style[t, 12, Bold]],
  Epilog -> {Red, Tooltip[Point[lim], lim]}],
 {{tmax, 10}, -9.75, 20, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]